# try catch finally in a method

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

What happens here ?
I wonder whether SaveError() can be called after exception block ?
Does the Main.cs get noticed about caught error?
I want to see the story behind this case.
What is the value of the variable "a" ?
note: Asume there has been an error in try block.

**Main.Cs**

```
public void RunAll()
{
  ....
  int  a = doSubTask();
}
```

**A.cs**

```
public int doSubTask(){
try{
..
..
 return 1;
}catch(Exception Ex)
{
throw new AppException("Error", ex);
}
finally
{
   SaveError();
   return -1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what u do you think finally block does?

Comment: @KamleshArya the question is obvious here.

Comment: The question is if you tried what happens.

Comment: Maybe a typo, but check the case of `foo` in the declaration and invocation.

Comment: @GOTO0 typo. Corrected in a clear naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return 0;` after the `finally` is redundant since `finally` will be called always even if there was an exception inside the cache or not.

Anyway, leaving the `finally` block with `return` will cause you a compilation error which means in your case, since you are throwing an exception from inside the `catch` block, a will not be set by any value.

Comment: Somewhat misleading. The `return 0;` is redundant (unreachable code) for this reason: The endpoint of the `try` block is unreachable (unconditionally ends in a `return`) ***and*** the endpoint of the `catch` block is unreacable too (always ends in a `throw` statement). The `finally` block is illegal. Code that attempts to leave the `finally` block will not compile. In other words the end point (the `}` ending the block) of the `finally` should be reachable (or the finally block should include an infinite loop, like a `while (true) { }`).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't return value within `finally` block, C# does not allow this.

`finally` always executes even if there are errors (i.e. control goes in catch block). So in your case, the return value will always be -1, it does not matter whether exception was thrown or not.

The last statement `return 0;` is non-reachable.

Comment: Upvoted because you said it is not possible to `return` from within `finally`. But how can you say the return value will be `-1` then? That is nonsense. Provided my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it depends from you machine ^^
As you can see in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx ,
if the exception is unhandled it's up to your system to decide if the Finally statement is executed or not.

Also: you can't return a value in a `finally` statement.

The whole method `Foo` seems a bit confusing to me.
If your goal is to try a "risky" operation and handle the error you shouldn't rethrow the exception without having the outer code handle that.

So, if you want the `RunAll` method to know if there's been an error, you should set it's code inside a `try`-`catch` statement and rethrow the exception in the `Foo` method, without the `finally` statement so the rethrown exception "bubbles up" the chain and gets handled in the calling method :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can modify your code like this. You shouldn't use more than one "return" key in a method.

```
    public int doSubTask()
    {
        int retval = 0;
        try
        {
            //to do
            retval = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            SaveError();
            retval = -1;
            throw new AppException("Error", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            // do something even there is error or not
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to try to "leave" a `finally` block, so it will not be valid to say `return -1;` inside the `finally` block. So your code will never compile.

> error CS0157: Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause

Hence, there exists no question "what will happen when it runs".